# Bash command to copy images from remote url

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm using mac's terminal.

I want to copy images from remote url: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/depot_b/public/images/ to a local directory.

What's the command to do that?

Tnx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively you may want just all the images, from a website. wget can do this with a recursive option such as:

$ wget -r -A=jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif,tiff,xpm,ico http://www.website.com/

This should only download the comma delimited extensions recursively starting at the site index. This works like a web-spider so if its not referenced anywhere on the site it will miss the image.

Comment: Unfortunately `wget` doesn't come on the Mac as part of the included developer pack. However, `curl` does.

Comment: Ah, good to know I was not aware of that... I've always installed the developer pack and then added my assortment of gnu tools.

Answer (score 4):

You can use curl

`curl -O "http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/depot_b/public/images/*.jpg"`

for example.

Comment: it's not work because I don't have access to the directory, I have only access to the index html contain the images names. I think the solution need to include regex. I just not so familiar with curl

Answer (score 1):

`wget` will work, assuming the server has directory listing:

```
wget -m http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/depot_b/public/images
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).  If I recall correctly, neither come out-of-the-box w/ OS X, so you may need to install them with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or something similar.

Comment: Curl comes with the Mac via the included developer pack, but not wget.