# How to download images from Google with terminal? (Mac)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, download

I'm trying to download pictures from Google in the Mac's terminal.
Please explain how to do this in the simplest way as I'm a complete beginner.
 Use this picture as the example please: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrqwY.jpg

I have already used

> curl -O https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrqwY.jpg

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5916276/499581, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32330737/499581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is fine but you need to use the URL of the image

```
curl -O https://i.imgur.com/PmPGYHR.png
```

If you want to get the image URL from the URL you referred, you can do

```
curl https://imgur.com/gallery/yu5An |grep "link rel=\"image_src" |cut -d'"' -f4
```